# How do you reset the SQL On Create trigger in a Logic App after a TRUNCATE TABLE?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

How do you reset the SQL On Create trigger in a Logic App after a `TRUNCATE TABLE`?

I have a basic logic app with a "When an item is created" [trigger against a SQL table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure#add-sql-trigger).

Inserting test records and it works fine.

Then ran a `TRUNCATE TABLE` on the test table.

After that, the logic app SQL trigger doesn't work **until** the new record has a value in the `IDENTITY` higher than the last successful run of the SQL trigger.

How can you *"reset the system"* so the logic app trigger will see all records as new after a `TRUNCATE TABLE`?

*And for my understanding, how does the logic app  trigger actually work "under the covers"? ... I thought it might be a trigger on the SQL table, but checked the db and can't see any trigger*

Comment: The question is **very** confusing as written. You'll have to make it crystal clear that you *aren't* referring to database triggers. `TRUNCATE TABLE` doesn't affect how database triggers work

Comment: From your description I suspect the "trigger" isn't actually a trigger but tries to detect changes periodically by storing the last seen IDENTITY value and querying for rows with a higher ID.

Comment: Consider using `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE TABLE`?

Answer (score 2):

That trigger is actually a polling job that checks for items with an ID larger than the MAX(ID) encountered in the last run. Losing records is an inherent problem with polling using an IDENTITY value. In fact, you'll find someone asking why this polling technique was used in the blog post that [introduced the SQL connector](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/)

**Reseeding IDENTITY**

The only solution when IDENTITY is used is to [reseed the IDENTITY value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-forcing-the-current-identity-value-to-a-new-value) with :

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Person.AddressType', RESEED, 10000);
```

Where 10000 is a number larger than the maximum IDENTITY value used before truncation.

A more robust solution would be to change the polling implementation to detect and use SQL Server's [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). Detecting For whatever reason, that wasn't implemented.

**Use Sequences instead of IDENTITY**

Another solution is to use a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of IDENTITY to generate new IDs. Sequences are independent database objects so truncating a table won't affect the sequence. In fact, you can use the same SEQUENCE as the default for multiple tables

For example, you can define this sequence :

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySequence
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

And use it as [the default constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-a-sequence-object-in-a-default-constraint) for a primary key :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable 
(
   ID bigint PRIMARY KEY 
)

ALTER TABLE MyTable  
ADD   
    DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR MySequence 
    FOR ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rely on a timestamp/rowversion column instead of an identity column. OnUpdate triggers for tables that do not have a column of this data type is not supported.

A SQL Connector query the change when an "item is created" trigger on a Logic App is set. It does not create a trigger on Azure SQL Database.  The SQL connector uses a polling mechanism to query a table for changes using a timestamp/rowversion column. This data type is specifically designed for this kind of processing in SQL. The polling query essentially selects all rows where the rowversion is greater than the last polled value.

Comment: The OP's problem is that the polling implementation fails if the table is truncated and the identity resets. Adding a rowversion won't change that. That's an *inherent* problem with using the max ID to detect insertions. A better implementation would use change tracking on the table and respond to `I` (insert) records

Comment: That trigger mechanism is not design to use without a timestamp column. If he adds a timestamp he will have a different behavior.

Comment: The rowversion is only used to detect single row modifications. It's the *IDENTITY* that's used to detect insertions. Adding a rowversion won't change anything - the rows are deleted already so there's no `rowversion` value to check. That's explained in the docs and blog posts [like this one](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/). Frankly, it's not a very good technique. SQL Server's change tracking could handle both scenarios easily

Comment: It's a serverless trigger really intended for distributed apps it certainly is not the common SQL Server trigger we know.

Comment: I didn't say it is. It has nothing to do with serverless either. It's polling, and the best option for polling is to use SQL Server's [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) that's available in all versions and editions since 2005. In fact, someone asks just that in the last comment in the blog post that [introduced the SQL connector](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introducing-triggers-in-the-sql-connector/): Why didn't they use Change Tracking?

Comment: In fact, `rowversion` is *inappropriate* for modification tracking as it's a `binary` type that can't be indexed. `rowversion` is only meant for optimistic concurrency. Using it for change tracking forces a full table scan to find out which rows changed. That simply can't scale

Comment: rowversion is extremely fast where there is no new data. When there is new data, the performance is comparable to a simple row query.

Comment: Fast doing what? It's a `binary` value. Those can't be indexed. You can't use it to find modified rows without a full table scan. It's fast only when used to check a *single* record.